# Feeds Import Question

Tags: 7, feeds

I have a feed set to Replace existing node and when I upload a feed say about 400 records, I see that 400 nodes were created.

Now if I upload that feed again right after the first one, I see 20 nodes updated.

Then if I upload again I might see 8 nodes updated

Does anyone know why this happens?

Comment: the content of the 8 feed source will be updated only therefore only 8 nodes will be updated.

Comment: Yes but why would it do that if I did not change anything in the import?

Comment: I am talking about your source of feeds from where you are importing. There the content of only 8 feed items will be changed therefore only 8 nodes are updated in your drupal site.